# Localizable strings and default values

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, default-value, localizable.strings

I have a *struct* for my local notifications, with an `init` that goes into *localizable.strings* and assigns the value corresponding to `key` to the body of the notification:

```
struct Notification {
    let identifier: String
    let body: String

init(withKey: String) {
    self.id = key
    self.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: key, arguments: nil)
}
```

So if my *localizable.strings* looks like this:

```
"testKey" = "Test Notification";
```

Then initializing a new `Notification` object will yield the following:

```
let notification = Notification(withKey: "testKey")
print(notification.body)                        // prints "Test Notification"
```

However, if I initialize the notification with a typo, the body is just going to be the mistyped key:

```
let mistypedNotification = Notification(withKey: "tstKey")
print(mistypedNotification.body)                 // prints "tstKey"
```

My desired behaviour is to have a **default** string be assigned to the body of the notification if the initializer is called with a key that does not currently exist in *localizable.strings*, as below:

```
let desiredNotification = Notification(withKey: "keyNotCurrentlyInLocalizableFile")
print(desiredNotification.body)           // prints "default string"
```

I know this can be achieved using one of the `NSLocalizedString` initializers, but in doing so, I would give up the benefits of using `NSString.localizedUserNotificationString`, which I don't want to do. Is there any way to achieve my desired behaviour without tapping into `NSLocalizedString`?

Comment: **Test** your code and avoid this edge case. Don't make unnecessary runtime checks which are supposed to be made during **design** time.

Comment: The documentation says: *“If a string resource corresponding to the specified key cannot be found, the returned string is empty.”* – which seems too be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is no key/value for the string in defaults , it returns the same string you specify so if they are equal that means you can specify a default value

```
let possibleBody =  NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: key, arguments: nil) 
self.body = possibleBody == key ? "defaultValue" : possibleBody
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a small drawback with the solution proposed by @Sh_Khan. If you don't have a translation for one of user's preferred languages at the time when the notification is created, then default value will be displayed. If later user adds a new language that your app supports, existing notifications won't adapt their strings to it as it's supposed to work with `localizedUserNotificationString`.

Sadly, Apple doesn't seem to support a direct way of supplying default values for localized notification strings as it does for normal localized strings.

I'd suggest just using your default values as keys where possible for notifications. And where it's not possible use the solution by @Sh_Khan.